# Calling Visual C++ DLL's functions from Delphi code

Tags: delphi, visual-c++, dll

In a Delphi program I'm using a DLL to control an external executable.
The DLL is written in Visual C++.
In C++ the code to use DLL is:

```
// defining pointer's type to a function compatible with 'launcher' function:
typedef int (WINAPI* PFI_HD_ST_N)(HDC, LPCSTR, int);
…
…
HINSTANCE m_hiDLLCTRL;  // handle to DLL instance
PFI_HD_ST_N pfStart;    // pointer to function that starts external program

// initialization
m_hiDLLCTRL = NULL;
pfStart = NULL;

// links DLL dynamically
m_hiDLLCTRL = LoadLibrary(“ExtProgCTRL.dll”);

// if DLL has been loaded
If (m_hiDLLCTRL)
    // I get the address to funcion that launches ExtProg
    pfStart = ( PFI_HD_ST_N) GetProcAddress( m_hiDLLCTRL, “ExtProgStart” );
// launches external program
If ( pfStart )
    // hWnd is handle to window where I want do draw 
    pfStart -> ( GetDC ( hWnd ), “C:\\Programs\\ExtProg”, 1 );
```

I have an equivalent code in Delphi:

```
private
    DLLHandle: THandle;
    XInt: function: Integer: cdecl;

...
implementation
...
...
DLLHandle := LoadLibrary('ExtProgCTRL.dll');
if DLLHandle <> 0 then
begin
    @XInt := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, ''ExtProgStart);
    if @XInt <> nil then
    begin
        MessageDlg('Function ExtProgStart loaded !', mtError, mbOKCancel, 0);
        ...
        ...
    end;
end;
```

It seems to work correctly, but I'm not able to find the Delphi code for the last instruction, to launch external program...

```
pfStart -> ( GetDC ( hWnd ), “C:\\Programs\\ExtProg”, 1 );
```

what in Delphi ?

I have changed:

```
private
    DLLHandle: THandle;
    XInt: function(DC: HDC; Text: PAnsiChar; SomeInt: Integer); Integer: cdecl;

...
implementation
...
retval: Integer;

DLLHandle := LoadLibrary('ExtProgCTRL.dll');
if DLLHandle <> 0 then
begin
    @XInt := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, ''ExtProgStart);
    if @XInt <> nil then
    begin
        MessageDlg('Function ExtProgStart loaded !', mtError, mbOKCancel, 0);
       retval := XInt(GetDC(hWnd), 'C:\Programs\ExtProg', 1);
    end;
end;
```

but now I have on last instruction : retval := XInt... the following error:
DCC Error : '(' expected but ')' found   (parenthesis after hWnd)

Comment: It looks like you've retyped some of this rather than using copy/paste. `pfStart -> ( GetDC ( hWnd ), “C:\\Programs\\ExtProg”, 1 )` is a syntax error I think and some of your quotes are messed up. I think I know what you mean, but using the clipboard helps us be sure we can see the exact same thing that you can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `XInt` like this:

```
XInt: function(DC: HDC; Text: PAnsiChar; SomeInt: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
```

1. You need to declare a parameter list that matches the definition in the C++ code.
2. I don't know meaningful names for the parameters but I'm sure you can supply them.
3. The C++ code specifies the `WINAPI` calling convention which matches `stdcall` in Delphi.

And then you can call it like this:

```
retval := XInt(GetDC(hWnd), 'C:\Programs\ExtProg', 1);
```

Comment: I have changed as You suggested.
Delphi gives an error on instruction retval := XInt...
GetDC(hWnd) isn't recognized ...

Comment: You didn't show all the code. So I can't see what you are looking at. What is not recognized?

Comment: You need to get a window handle, hwnd, say. I can't work out where you'll get that from. I think I answered the question you asked.